# Applescript File naming

Tags: applescript, filenames

Code snippet:

```
 tell application "Finder" to set new_item to ¬
 (container of this_item as string) & (name of this_item) & "s"
 save this_image in new_item as typ
```

Its saving the file as filename.pngs I want it to save as filenames.png.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save this as an application, then you can drop things on it and it will copy them adding an s to the name. Or you can double-click it and it will ask you to choose a file to copy. **NOTE**: change the property ***appendText*** if you want to change the text (i.e. "s") that's added to the name.

Notice the handler **getName_andExtension(f)**. That's what I use to get the name and extension from a file. I use that to calculate the new path when adding the s.

I hope that helps!

```
property appendText : "s"

on run
    set f to choose file
    duplicateInPlace_appendingText(f, appendText)
end run

on open the_items
    repeat with f in the_items
        duplicateInPlace_appendingText(f, appendText)
    end repeat
end open

on duplicateInPlace_appendingText(f, textToAppend)
    set f to f as text
    set {nm, ex} to getName_andExtension(f)
    tell application "Finder" to set theContainer to (container of item f) as text

    if ex is "" then
        set new_path to theContainer & nm & textToAppend
    else
        set new_path to theContainer & nm & textToAppend & "." & ex
    end if

    do shell script "cp -R " & quoted form of POSIX path of f & space & quoted form of POSIX path of new_path
end duplicateInPlace_appendingText

on getName_andExtension(f)
    set f to f as text
    set {name:nm, name extension:ex} to info for file f without size
    if ex is missing value then set ex to ""
    if ex is not "" then
        set nm to text 1 thru ((count nm) - (count ex) - 1) of nm
    end if
    return {nm, ex}
end getName_andExtension
```

Comment: This helps alot. I hope I am not asking for too much but anyway you can merge that with this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004092804461334 ? I want to drag multiple (no included in the resize script I included) images on it and add the s (for small) name to it once it is resized. Thanks so much again.

Comment: This is where you need to try. I showed you the getName_andExtension(f) handler and you can see the code to calculate the name as you prefer. So just put that in the other code in place of where the other code calculates the name.

Comment: I understand the "give help and let them do it themselves" method when someone is trying to learn programming. This is a one time situation that I'll have to deal with applescript (PHP person here), so its really not worth me learning all the syntax and commands and what not, I was hoping to get A-Z help on this one. Nevertheless thanks, upvoted and checked your answer!

Answer (score 0):

`name of this_item` gives the full name of the Finder item, including the file extension. You need to split it up. Unfortunately, this isn't as easy as it could be. You could do something like:

```
tell application "Finder"
    get the selection 
    set {dispname, ext, exthidden} to {displayed name, name extension, extension hidden} of item 1 of the result
end tell

if exthidden then
    dispname & "s." & ext
else
    ((characters 1 through -(2 + (count of ext)) of dispname) as string) & "s." & ext
end if
```

That just builds the modified name for the first item in the Finder selection, without doing anything with it.

Comment: Hey, Never written an apple script but how do I integrate that into the code? http://pastebin.com/GHaQCcex

Comment: Also anyway to process multiple files dragged onto the script?

Comment: @NoviceCoding - You integrate it by opening up your existing script in AppleScript Editor and using the suggested code to change how the name for the new file is defined.